# Map having keys as objects

Tags: javascript

The documentation on `Map` on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) says

> A Map's keys can be any value (including functions, objects, or any primitive).

Let's say we have

```js
let a = new Map();
a.set({a: 1, b:3}, "Hello");
a.set({a: 1, b:3}, "World");
```

This produces a map with 2 elements instead of one.

How can I make the lookup of keys to be in terms of their values and not their ids?

Or alternatively, how can I make a Map where the key is a pair of unordered values?

Comment: Your code is not replacing duplicate keys because your key is an anonymous object. Javascript will not mark it as duplicate because it will check your key by reference.  He does not know what is inside of your object. Since you are providing key directly it will not work. Like if you create const key = {a:1, b: 3}; and try to add a.set(key, "Hello") and a.set(key, "World"); It will override Hello with World.

Comment: Convert your key to a canonicalized string.

Comment: @NavnathJadhav He knows that, he's asking how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a workaround that will store things in the way you intend. Albeit, it does not use the `Map` class and the assigning function is not a method of any class.

```js
set=function(a,o,v){a[[o.a,o.b].sort().join(",")]=v};
const a = {};

set(a,{a: 1, b:3}, "Hello");
set(a,{a: 3, b:1}, "World");
set(a,{a: 2, b:2}, "something else");

console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to understand that two object initialized with same values will never be equal to each other. Try running the following snippet.

**Hence map creates two different elements with it**.

```js
var x = {a: 1, b:3};
var y = {a: 1, b:3};
var z = x;

console.log(x === y); // => false
console.log(x === z); // => true
```

Therefore, if you wish to group based on `object` as `keys` you will probably have to pass the objects as `references` as shown below:

```js
let a = new Map();
let key = {a: 1, b:3};
a.set(key, "Hello");
a.set(key, "World");

console.log(a.get(key));
```

**Alternatively** instead of keeping track to references for each key, you can just stringify the object like so:

```js
let a = new Map();
let key = JSON.stringify({a: 1, b:3});
a.set(key, "Hello");
a.set(key, "World");

console.log(a.get(key));
```